# SQL server 2012 service pack installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation

which service pack I should apply first after installing sql server 2012 enterprise edition either sp1 or sp2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sp2 does not require sp1, so sp2

Comment: Thanks Alex for your quick help. Can you explain me why sp2 does ot require sp1?

Comment: As answered below they are cumulative, sp2 will include everything in sp1, as well as updated versions of sp1 components, so the existence of sp1 is not required.

Comment: What's wrong with SP3?

Answer (score 1):

The service packs are cumulative, so sp2 includes any pieces from sp1 that were not subsequently updated in sp2.

Answer (score -1):

The Best Practices, that I've been following would be to start initially with SP1 and will check how it behaves and then will upgrade it to SP2.

Depending upon the application and other various parameters its better to first implement such upgrades on DEV/TEST server first and monitor the behavior accordingly. Once everything goes well you can decide how to apply SP's on the production box.

Also, note that Cumulative updates are the one which are truly cumulative. i.e if i need to install SQL server 2012 CU9, i can go like installing SQL server 2012 RTM , then SP2 and then directly CU9, instead of installing CU's from 1-9..

You can refer [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/) for the SP releases.